# Administration of telegram channel

Tags: channel, telegram

I get into a problem with the Telegram channel,
one person creates a channel and adds other administrators to it,
then she removed her telegram. and now it is needed to add another telegram administrator to that channel.
As I understand, the only channel creator can add a new admin of the channel.

So.. what should I do?
I think even she(channel creator) reinstalls her telegram, she can't add a new admin to the channel...

Comment: This question would look better on SuperUser, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if someone deletes their telegram account then bots they created are deleted, and groups or channels lose their master and no one gets the master card

https://telegram.wiki/privacy/accountdeletion

> What happens after account deletion?

> User will get automatically logged out of their Telegram clients.

> Username and the phone number of a deleted account immediately become available to reuse.

> If the user recreates the Telegram account with the same phone number, the TQ will change.
> The account will have the same phone number but will be a fresh new account with a different unique ID (#tq number).

> TDesktop (Windows) will still show the old account's display name, even after restarting the client. The name does not change to DELETED / Unknown / Hidden Name, etc. This is at least if you had a previous chat history with the old deleted account. If you re log in, the name will show as blank (no name at all). Other Telegram clients may display deleted accounts as DELETED / Unknown / Hidden Name, depending on the client and language/translation strings.

> User's last seen will display as “Last seen a long time ago” in modern clients (“offline” in very old clients)
> You can still type to a deleted account, but the messages will never be received by the Telegram servers. They will always show a clock icon, instead of 1 check.

> Bots created from a deleted account are deleted too and their usernames become available to reuse.

> **Groups and channels aren't deleted and stay orphaned (no one gets privileges of the creator).**

update: I'm a quite sure telegram was updated so that if an admin leaves a group or channel (by manually leaving or deleting their account) then the user who was connected for the longest gets the admin control... (bots still lose their admin and become useless)
(I couldn't quickly find the source for this, quite sure it was in one of the update telegraphs they sent when the change happened)

Answer (score 1):

Telegram doesn't work like that. It is completely on the cloud. This means that if she reinstalls her Telegram app, it will be as if she hasn't uninstalled it. (Uninstalling is different from removing your account)

Comment: she has removed her account.